# Why is my Oracle AQ so slow with multi-consumer queue

Tags: oracle, queue, jms, oracle-aq

new to Oracle AQ, but it seems like it should really make things easy for the project I am working on.

I want to create a queue with multiple durable subscribers, but I have found in testing that everything slows down once there are 2 subscribers listening.

When I have one subscriber listening, everything is fast.  I create new messages in the queue and almost instantly they are consumed by the listener.

Then I add another listener from another server.  Instantly Oracle slows down.  It takes 60+ seconds to create a message in the queue.  The message isn't consumed until a few minutes later.

I am wondering, is there a lot more overhead when the queue is multi-consumer?  Is that overhead only when the server starts up?  Or will it always be there?

I ran a second test using a single-consumer queue and did not have these problems.

Perhaps I have done something wrong in my listener configuration?

This is how I set up my queue table:

```
EXEC dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table(queue_table=>'MY_QUEUE_TABLE',
     queue_payload_type=>'sys.aq$_jms_text_message',
     multiple_consumers=>TRUE);
```

And this is my configuration:

```
<jms:listener-container 
        connection-factory="AQjmsFactory"
        container-type="default"
        destination-type="durableTopic"
        client-id="MY-ADAPTER" 
        acknowledge="transacted">
    <jms:listener destination="MYA_INFO_QUEUE" ref="personUpdateListener" subscription="MYADAPTERJ"/>
    <jms:listener destination="MYB_INFO_QUEUE" ref="courseUpdateListener" subscription="MYADAPTERJ"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

Comment: What database version / patchset? What is the value of aq_tm_processes startup parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really "overhead" so much as how the model works with multiple subscribers. There is a certain amount of "spin-up" and "spin-down" time with the messaging. That said, the database is still relatively idle during these delays. You shouldn't see significant CPU/Memory/IO consumption while waiting for the processing to begin.

If I understand how things work, there are background jobs which handle the AQ messages which run at specific intervals. When the job is not running, you don't burn any cycles, but nothing is happening either. It's like saying that your Ferrari is slow when the engine isn't running, or while you're sitting at red lights.

To test *performance*, you should probably not worry about these idle times so much as when there are many messages in the queue to be processed. That is, when the Ferrari is on the open road!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your analogy.  It's more like this, when I'm driving the Ferarri alone it's really fast.  As soon as one other person gets in the car, everything slows down ( for-i-don't-know-how-long )